# bad estimates generating long running query plan

Tags: postgresql

Here is my query

```
select echo.romeo AS november_india,november_mike.four ,november_mike.meter_type, november_mike.action, november_mike.four, november_mike.status, november_mike.request_id, november_mike.reference_id, november_mike.response_code, november_mike.touch_time, november_mike.transparent_data
from MDM_CONTEXT november_mike
LEFT JOIN quebec_six alpha ON november_mike.november_india = alpha.quebec_six
AND alpha.three = 'papa' AND alpha.seven = (SELECT max(india.seven)
FROM quebec_six india WHERE november_mike.november_india = india.quebec_six AND india.three = 'papa')
LEFT JOIN ATTRIBUTES echo ON alpha.uniform = echo.uniform AND echo.golf = 'Hotel' WHERE november_mike.three = 'papa' and echo.romeo IS NOT NULL AND november_mike.four > 1614556800000 AND november_mike.four <= 1614592403000
ORDER BY november_mike.four;
```

Postgres planner generating plan which uses nested loop and runs longer -- since it runs long dont have explain analyze output, simple explain plan output is here

```
Sort  (cost=60599.10..60599.10 rows=1 width=202)
    Sort Key: november_mike.four
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8713.91..60599.09 rows=1 width=202)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=8713.48..36958.43 rows=1 width=203)
                Hash Cond: (((november_mike.november_india)::text = (alpha.quebec_six)::text) AND ((SubPlan 2) = alpha.seven))
              ->  Seq Scan on quebec_four november_mike  (cost=0.00..27811.99 rows=1900 width=194)
                      Filter: ((four > 'six'::bigint) AND (four <= 'lima_alpha'::bigint) AND ((three)::text = 'papa'::text))
              ->  Hash  (cost=5394.12..5394.12 rows=221290 width=40)
                    ->  Seq Scan on quebec_six alpha  (cost=0.00..5394.12 rows=221290 width=40)
                            Filter: ((three)::text = 'papa'::text)
              SubPlan 2
                ->  Result  (cost=4.44..4.45 rows=1 width=8)
                      InitPlan
                        ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8)
                              ->  Index Only Scan Backward using lima_seven on quebec_six india  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8)
                                      Index Cond: ((quebec_six = (november_mike.november_india)::text) AND (three = 'papa'::text) AND (seven five NOT NULL))
        ->  Index Scan using xray on two echo  (cost=0.43..23640.65 rows=1 width=24)
                Index Cond: ((uniform)::text = (alpha.uniform)::text)
                Filter: ((romeo five NOT NULL) AND ((golf)::text = 'hotel'::text))
```

To get the explain analyze, disabled nested loop by setting enable_nestloop to off - this makes query run fast. This shows the planner is estimating one record from the top hash join but in actual has 2048 records, how to fix this bad estimate? Please help.

There is no bloat on the tables and stats are up to date.

```
Sort  (cost=124830.96..124830.96 rows=1 width=202) (actual time=895.166..895.455 rows=2408 loops=1)
    Sort Key: november_mike.four
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 761kB
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=36958.44..124830.95 rows=1 width=202) (actual time=432.262..893.729 rows=2408 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: ((echo.uniform)::text = (alpha.uniform)::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on two echo  (cost=0.00..87461.58 rows=109578 width=24) (actual time=29.056..475.163 rows=110645 loops=1)
                Filter: ((romeo five NOT NULL) AND ((golf)::text = 'hotel'::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 3049715
        ->  Hash  (cost=36958.43..36958.43 rows=1 width=203) (actual time=403.128..403.134 rows=2408 loops=1)
                Buckets: 4096 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 522kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=8713.48..36958.43 rows=1 width=203) (actual time=195.253..401.973 rows=2408 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: (((november_mike.november_india)::text = (alpha.quebec_six)::text) AND ((SubPlan 2) = alpha.seven))
                    ->  Seq Scan on quebec_four november_mike  (cost=0.00..27811.99 rows=1900 width=194) (actual time=102.957..238.627 rows=2408 loops=1)
                            Filter: ((four > 'six'::bigint) AND (four <= 'lima_alpha'::bigint) AND ((three)::text = 'papa'::text))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 613167
                    ->  Hash  (cost=5394.12..5394.12 rows=221290 width=40) (actual time=91.389..91.390 rows=221290 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 18789kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on quebec_six alpha  (cost=0.00..5394.12 rows=221290 width=40) (actual time=0.025..43.606 rows=221290 loops=1)
                                  Filter: ((three)::text = 'papa'::text)
                    SubPlan 2
                      ->  Result  (cost=4.44..4.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=4816)
                            InitPlan
                              ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=4816)
                                    ->  Index Only Scan Backward using lima_seven on quebec_six india  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=4816)
                                            Index Cond: ((quebec_six = (november_mike.november_india)::text) AND (three = 'papa'::text) AND (seven five NOT NULL))
                                            Heap Fetches: 0
```

Update - 3/8/2021

After removing alpha.seven = (...), below is the explain plan.

```
Sort  (cost=134009.09..134011.97 rows=1154 width=202) (actual time=859.357..859.648 rows=2434 loops=1)
    Sort Key: november_mike.four
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 769kB
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=45790.14..133950.39 rows=1154 width=202) (actual time=330.276..857.769 rows=2434 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: ((echo.uniform)::text = (alpha.uniform)::text)
        ->  Seq Scan on two echo  (cost=0.00..87723.95 rows=113269 width=24) (actual time=19.106..531.294 rows=110671 loops=1)
                Filter: ((romeo five NOT NULL) AND ((golf)::text = 'hotel'::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 3063312
        ->  Hash  (cost=45761.97..45761.97 rows=2254 width=203) (actual time=311.095..311.097 rows=2434 loops=1)
                Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 526kB
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=8160.25..45761.97 rows=2254 width=203) (actual time=176.821..310.209 rows=2434 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: ((november_mike.november_india)::text = (alpha.quebec_six)::text)
                    ->  Seq Scan on quebec_four november_mike  (cost=0.00..37570.86 rows=2218 width=194) (actual time=86.580..218.641 rows=2408 loops=1)
                            Filter: ((four > 'six'::bigint) AND (four <= 'lima'::bigint) AND ((three)::text = 'papa'::text))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 821960
                    ->  Hash  (cost=5394.12..5394.12 rows=221290 width=32) (actual time=89.518..89.518 rows=221342 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16097kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on quebec_six alpha  (cost=0.00..5394.12 rows=221290 width=32) (actual time=0.034..42.312 rows=221342 loops=1)
                                  Filter: ((three)::text = 'papa'::text)
```

Comment: In your query, is `hotel` supposed to be quoted?  Is `romeo five` supposed to have an underscore between the words?

Comment: What are the plan estimates if you drop the `alpha.seven = (...)`?  The current plan doesn't give enough info to know if that is the driver of the bad selectivity estimate or if it is the join condition.

Comment: You are correct, the converter missed those things, updated the query, please check. As for the alpha.seven estimates, let me get back on that.

Comment: Updated original post with the updated plan when alpha.seven is dropped. Looks like alpha.seven was causing bad estimates correct.

Comment: [Are your table statistics up to date?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html)

Comment: Yes Schwern, the tables stats are up to date with vacuum as well.